# Return true/false based on elapsed time from SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say we have an SQL query such as below

```
select now()-insert_time AS time_elapsed, *
from account
where enabled = true AND machine = 'one'
limit 1
```

is it possible to return a boolean column for `now()-insert_time AS time_elapsed`? I want it to be true if it's more than 4 hours, and false if it's less than 4 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare it directly in your query

```
 select now()-insert_time AS time_elapsed,
        now()-insert_time >= '4 hours' as status,
        * 
   from account 
  where enabled = true
```

In generally, you put it in `CASE` expression for other value output

```
 select now()-insert_time AS time_elapsed,
        CASE 
             WHEN now()-insert_time >= '4 hours' THEN 'Greater than 4 hours'
             ELSE 'Less than 4 hours'
        END as status,
        * 
   from account 
  where enabled = true 
        AND machine = 'one'  
  limit 1
```

Hopefully it will help you.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes. This is my wrong mind set. I'll update my answer.